# Patch of green space on island where nothing grows

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I have a decent patch of "green space" that extends over and past my island's eastern beach. When I've tried to plant things in that space, they don't seem to grow, even though I'm pretty positive they have enough space to do so.

Is this fixable, e.g., with the terraforming tool, or does it just get to be the spot I keep my picnic stuff on? To give an idea of the size, it's almost, but not quite, the same general dimensions of a house plot (I also tried to put a house there, but it's *just* a bit too small.

Comment: maybe we can get a screenshot? If youre talking about the island peninsula, then you should be able to get a tree on there. I do, and flowers. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm hoping to have some time to get a screenshot here shortly. I had tried planting bamboo and trees, but I'd tried to put more than one, which may be the issue. It looks like it has the space for multiple, though?

Comment: you can really only get 1, maybe 2 tree/bamboo on it. go nuts with flowers though.

Comment: @Rapitor If you want, post this as an answer....I'll get some flowers on there tonight and can see how they do. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Island Peninsulas aren't that big, they may seem so, but they vary rarely go over 3x3 (a tree needs 3x3). They round out and add some extra land, though not always a full grid space. so you can likely fit two trees on one at best. Most players I've come across use this peninsula for furniture arrangements instead, like Lighthouses or small picnic areas. It seems to be Designed/intended for that.

Answer (score 2):

As Rapitor [asserts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/367733/112281), it is unlikely to be a problem with the land per-se, and much more likely an issue of hole area.

One way to confirm whether or not a space is valid for growing trees is to... try and plant a fully grown tree there!

Simply chomp a fruit, add a nearby tree to your pockets, then approach your target hole and attempt to "plant" the tree from your inventory.

If the hole is in a valid position, your villager will insert the fully grown tree into the spot. **If the hole is invalid for planting, your character will say as much.**